# Spring binding abstract Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a problem with the form-databinding in Spring.

Given is an Object with the following structure:

```
- SiteContent
|-List<Panel> boxList
```

the panel element looks like this:

```
- Panel
|- Collection<AbstractPanelElement> panelElements
```

The collection with the `AbstractPanelElements` is the critical point, because it is possible that the `AbstractPanelElements` is a `Divider`, `Address` or `Icon`.

If i submit a form that contains several elements of these types i get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: 
    Invalid property 'boxList[0].panelElements[0]' of bean class [com.panel.SiteContent]: 
    Illegal attempt to get property 'panelElements' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NullValueInNestedPathException: 
    Invalid property 'boxList[0].panelElements' of bean class [com.panel.SiteContent]: 
    Could not instantiate property type [com.panel.AbstractPanelElement] to auto-grow nested property path: java.lang.InstantiationException
```

After research i found that it is possible that we can set the following (InitBinder) in the Controller:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
    binder.setAutoGrowNestedPaths(false);
}
```

But this doesn't solve the problem, it makes sence, i think spring can't instantiate a abstract class.

Now my question, is it possible that i can solve this issue or is there no way?

Comment: when this exception happened ? cause a NullValueInNestedPathException seems to appears when boxList.panelElements is null and you try to add elements to it.

Comment: the exception would be thrown after the form submit. i debug it and recognize that if spring try to instantiate the panelElement (`AbstractPanelElement`)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide your own Binding methods and then create the correct subtypes. Spring wouldn't know otherwise which of the subtypes should be instantiated for which element.

One example is something like this:

```
@ModelAttribute("item")
public Item getItem(final HttpServletRequest request){
    String type = request.getParameter("type");
    if (type!=null){
        if (type.equals(TYPE1.class.getSimpleName())){
            return new TYPE1();
        }
        if (type.equals(TYPE2.class.getSimpleName())){
            return new TYPE2();
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("OH NOES! Type unknown!");
    }
    return null; 
}
```

You can modify this to handle the list items as well.
In the back of my head I know that there are PropertyEditors that you can implement to go from string representation to a class. But I have limited time to research right now.

This might help you:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-beans-conversion-customeditor-registration